# Proxy requests from webpack dev server to .net MVC site

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to integrate Vue in my .net MVC project. I've installed Vue using the [CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and added the following `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://mvcsite.local',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  runtimeCompiler: true
};
```

The proxy works fine, except that a request to the root `http://localhost:8080` (which the dev server runs at) serves the index.html generated by Vue, rather than proxying the request to the root of `http://mvcsite.local`. How do I proxy that particular request?

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Marco There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in your comment, there is an open issue on github for this, so currently there seems to be no fix. In my case (ASP.NET MVC 4) I solved the problem using a workaround. I simply move the root dir to /Home in development environment. Of course your server backend has to support this scenario, but that's usually the smaller problem. My working vue.config.js for @vue/cli 3 looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

publicPath: "/Home",

devServer: {
    publicPath: "/Home",
    proxy:
    {
        '^/Home/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:50353/',
            ws: true,
            changeOrigin: true
        }

    },

}
```

Comment: I'll accept this workaround until a proper fix is in place :)